# Android rendering error when using setFillAfter on Animation

Tags: android, animation

I got strange problem when using `setFillAfter(boolean flag)` to make it keep position after animation.

It start drawing error like the image below.

[image: the drawing got some error, it does not redraw properly]

My animation code is:

```
RotateAnimation rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(rotation, -rotation, box.getX() + box.getWidth() / 2, box.getY() + 150);
rotateAnimation.setDuration(500);

AnimationSet returnAnimation = new AnimationSet(true);
returnAnimation.addAnimation(rotateAnimation);
// I use AnimationSet because I want to add one more TranslateAnimation later
returnAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
```

I have no idea how to fix this. If I remove the `setFillAfter`, the animation will not keep its state after finish.

I have tried adding an AnimationListener and call `clearAnimation` on `animationEnd` but it does not work.

Please help me. Thank you very much!

Comment: Have you tried Property Animation?

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the solution, but not the best one.

I called the animation code above on touch up event (`MotionEvent.ACTION_UP`). And on touch move event (`MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE`), it should be:

```
returnAnimation.setFillAfter(false);
box.clearAnimation();
```

And no more render error on the screen.

The completed code should be:

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        //...
        returnAnimation.setFillAfter(false);
        box.clearAnimation();
        //...
        break;
   case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //...
        returnAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        box.startAnimation(returnAnimation);
        //...
        break;
}
```

But the big problem is `setFillAfter(boolean flag)` is a fake state function, and the view does not change it real position after the animation.

I need to find the better solution.

**@sandrstar** has suggested me using Property Animation. I will try it.